# Text replacement not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

For the last 2 weeks, text replacement on my iPhone has not worked.

I have have tried deleting the existing ones then re-creating them, but it still not working.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of iOS 12, Apple appears to have placed a 128 character limit on text replacement. A simple workaround using the [Google Keyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gboard-the-google-keyboard/id1091700242?mt=8) will allow you to use your saved iOS keyboard shortcuts.

This is not ideal, but unless Apple releases an update, this is the best option. Once you install the Gboard, you should be able to use your text replacement shortcuts as before.

I wrote a post on the workaround: [Link](https://timleland.com/text-replacement-not-working-ios12/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to fix this are the same as many data corruption issues.

1. Back up the phone

   1. Take care to unsync any Apple Watches
   2. Take care to backup health data by choosing an encrypted backup option
   3. Verify a good backup (or two)
2. Settings app - erase all content and settings
3. Set up phone as new - test one substitution to ensure it's not needing a full OS restore
4. Erase content and settings a second time, then restore from backup

Answer (score 1):

I've found restarting my device activates recent entries...just ask SIRI, "Hey, Siri, restart my [ iPhone / iPad ]"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is Siri relevant? You need to concentrate on providing enough information to confirm a simple reboot fulfils an answer to the question.

Comment: While the answer is quite brief @AndyGriffiths, it is a clean and succinct answer.  Siri is used to show *a quick way to restart the phone* and it clearly states that this solution is based on anecdotal evidence.  I can’t speak to its effectiveness as I don’t have this issue, but this is a bona fide and complete answer.

Comment: Fair enough, @Allan. It just felt like it was an unnecessary addition, and could easily be read as an essential part of the procedure. Also, the question is asking re deleting text replacement entries, not how to reboot a phone.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths, please remember, that *Review* isn't for "correctness" of an answer, but whether it's an answer to the question.  The author could have said "I have found that if you dance in circle around the iPhone and then sacrifice a rubber chicken, it will fix the problem."  It would have been completely wrong, but still technically an answer.  Up/Down voting is where correctness/accuracy applies.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply put the description and the shortcuts into the wrong fields. Please check for this kind of input error.